# SpringBoot & embedded Tomcat: Unpack executable war on server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I made my first web app with spring. It's really neat to work with. Currently, I'm having an executable war file, that contains everything, including a tomcat server. It runs fine.
There is only one thing that bothers me. Quick debugging  and maintenance are for JavaScript and CSS is not very comfortable, as the war file will not get unpacked any more on the server. Means, I always have to restart the whole application to take over this changes. That is really annoying.

How can I set-up a spring project with an embedded Tomcat server, so it will unpack on execution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose:

1. Run on a packed-executable war
2. Deploy the war on a Tomcat, so the war is unpacked and you can edit CSS and JS without re-deploying.

With Gradle it's easy to re-generate and run the war again, o I'd rather to work with an executable war

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a perfect solution, but for faster turn around times in your testing you can leverage Spring developer tools with live reload on the browser.  This will let you make changes and save them locally.  That will be detected in your IDE which will restart your application and then trigger your browser's live reload plugin to automatically refresh your page.

https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-developer-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-traditional-deployment

Build a traditional deployable war file, then you could run it by two ways:

1) java -jar myproject.war

2) deploy it into tomcat, like %TOMCAT_HOME%\webapps\myproject.war

For #2, you could find the folder %TOMCAT_HOME%\webapps\myproject unpacked after tomcat started, and then some of files could be changed easily, such as, js, css, jsp, etc...

Here is an example [eg-spring-boot-war](https://github.com/lenicliu/eg-spring/tree/master/eg-spring-boot/eg-spring-boot-war)